# What's the "single" derivation of omni?

Tags: single-word-requests, latin

So we know "omni" is a prefix indicating encompassing of everything. We could say, omnidirectional for example, which is "receiving signals from or transmitting in all directions."

What would be the counterpart for just a single direction?

I just found this [resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix) so maybe the answer is "uni"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: I provided the following answer before the question was edited to suggest the same word. However, it confirms the suggestion.

---

What you're looking for is [**uni-**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uni-):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : one : single
> // *uni*cellular

In the example in the question, the complement of *omnidirectional* is [*unidirectional*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unidirectional).

Answer (score 1):

**Mono-** could also be used.

> A prefix that means “one, only, single,” as in *monochromatic*, having only one color.
>
> It is often found in chemical names where it means “containing just one” of the specified atom or group, as in *carbon monoxide*, which is carbon attached to a single oxygen atom.

[[Dictionary.com]](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mono-)

Comment: Since 'omni-' has its origins in Latin it makes more sense to consider 'uni-' as its opposite since 'uni-' is derived from Latin whereas 'mono-' is derived from Greek. The opposite of the 'mono-' prefix would be 'pan-'. For example the contrast between 'monotheism' and 'pantheism' (taking the definition of 'pantheism' as the worship of all gods.